Have metal ships ever used ramming as a regular tactic?
Have metal ships ever used ramming as a regular tactic, as wooden ships used to?
A one-off incident night be interesting, but did any navy ever use ramming of other metal ships by its own as a regular tactic?

Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s). At a minimum, all questions should explain why Wikipedia is insufficient.

Although I doubt it was "official" tactics for destroyer-escorts to ram surfaced submarines during the Second World War, it did occur on numerous occasions.
The usual scenario was for the destroyer-escorts to work over a submerged U-boat and force it to the surface.  Once on the surface, the range was usually too close for the destroyer-escort's large guns to depress low enough to engage directly, the submarine was probably trying to line up its torpedoes or man its own deck gun, and it was more expedient to simply ram the submarine.
Additionally, while the destroyer-escort was likely to finish the encounter with some minor damage, the submarine would be in a lot of trouble.
I am mostly aware of this because my grandfather served on CVE-21 Block Island, which conducted ASW patrols.  On her ill-fated last cruise off northwest Africa, one her escorts, USS Buckley (DE-51) rammed U-66.  My grandfather had pictures of Buckley after the encounter, as well as pictures of the U-66 prisoners who were transferred to Block Island.
In a similar action, USS Thomas (DE-102) rammed U-233 while escorting for USS Card (CVE-11).

Ramming submarines was close to an official tactic during WWI, when anti-submarine weapons were much more limited. HMS Dreadnaught became the only battleship to sink a submarine (U-29) in this way,

Oddball comment: the Wikipedia entry for U-66 shows how little damage Buckley sustained, and some of the U-66 crew on Block Island.  The picture there is not my grandfather's picture.  I'm guessing the crew had quite the photo op on Block Island when they arrived.  I also like the joker smiling in the middle of the front row: he knew the war was done for him.

Smiles and PW skivvy shirts sure beat the alternative.  I suspect the key word in the OP is "regular."

Yes, but it was mostly a bad idea.
There was a time when armor was racing ahead of cannon, and naval architects got the idea of ram tactics.

The 1866 battle of Lissa involved many rammings.
HMS Vanguard was accidentally rammed and sunk, and HMS Victoria hit HMS Camperdown, which convinced some experts that ramming was viable -- despite the fact that HMS Iron Duke or the Victoria and Camperdown were not enough under control to avoid the ramming.

